# Visual Basic Run-time error '91' when setting new Object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA, but not to programming. I'm trying to set up a shared instance of a class, and I keep running into Run-time error 91, where it complains about the variable not being set.

```
'A Module which acts as the singleton loader
Option Explicit
Private instance As GroceryDatabase

Public Function sharedInstance() As GroceryDatabase
    If instance Is Nothing Then
        Set instance = New GroceryDatabase 'Run-time error 91 thrown here
    End If

    Set sharedInstance = instance
End Function
```

Obviously the variable isn't set yet, which is why I'm assigning it a New GroceryDatabase. I've seen a lot of answers to this question that boil down to someone attempting to use a Nothing object, but I can't really understand why this is being thrown when I try to instantiate it.

Comment: Is your error at the" set instance =..."? Does your constructor for grocerydatabase work when you step through the code?

Comment: Aha, I threw a breakpoint into the constructor of GroceryDatabase, and it turns out there was a variable in there that's actually throwing the error. I'm going to answer my own question, thank you!

Comment: Another way to catch these is to set `Tools>Options>General>Break in Class Modules`

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the suggestions

Comment: @Chris glad you got it. Otherwise your posted code looks ok

Answer (score 0):

The error was not specifically due to the line where the object was instantiated, but instead because of an issue in its constructor where there was in fact a variable being assigned but not Set.

This was discovered by putting a breakpoint in the constructor for GroceryDatabase. For the future, I've enabled "Break in Class Modules", found in the path Tools>Options>General. Now, the issue is immediately pinpointed when pressing the "debug" button.